# Curve drawable without vector - xml Android

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I am trying to draw this on `xml drawable`:

[image]

With Vector it is easy but it is showing "concurrent mark sweep GC" on logcat and it is causing the device to slow-down.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="180"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="180">
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:left="-100dp"
            android:right="-100dp"
            android:top="-80dp">


            <shape android:shape="oval">
                <size android:height="20dp" />
                <gradient
                    android:angle="0"
                    android:centerColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:endColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:type="linear" />
            </shape>


        </item>

        <item>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" />
        </item>

    </layer-list>

</rotate>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Ok, made! Thank you again